# how do I write an IF ELSE into this query to make it work?

Tags: mysql

table looks something like this: (yes those are `&` signs. ignore the dashes)

```
ID-VALUE-NUM
-1-YES----2-
-1-NO-----3-
-2-YES----1-
-2-NO-----1-
-3-&&&----1-
-3-&------2-
-3-&&-----2-
```

what I need to do:

for each `ID`, I need to get the value with the highest `NUM`, in the case of a tie and `VALUE` has `&`s then it would pick the shortest. if the value is `YES/NO` then it will pick `YES`.

result desired

```
ID-VALUE-NUM
-1-NO-----3-
-2-YES----1-
-3-&------2-
```

I think I have to put a `IF` statement in there somewhere but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.  The join finds the maximum `num`.  Then the `select` uses logic to choose the right value based on your rules:

```
select t.id,
       (case when count(*) = 1 then min(value)
             when max(value like '%&%') > 0 then min(value)
             when max(value = 'Yes') > 0 and max(value = 'No') > 0 then 'Yes'
             else max(value)
        end) as value,
       t.num
from t join
     (select id, max(num) as maxnum
      from t
      group by id
     ) tm
     on t.id = tm.id and t.num = tm.maxnum
group by t.id, t.num
```

Comment: returned 0 rows. something wrong with `on t.id = tm.maxnum` I think?

Comment: @Sam . . . Yes, I fixed the join.